# AzureAD authentication to Icingaweb2

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, icingaweb2

Is it possible to authenticate to Icingaweb2 through AzureAD (SAML/oauth2/openID) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing is actually possible to achieve with usage of
https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy

1. After this proxy is installed and configured, run it with `-set-xauthrequest` info is in github repo wiki/readme
2. Set up icingaweb2 for external authentication by adding:

   ```
   [autologin]
   backend = external
   ```

   into `authentication.ini` file
3. In icingaweb2 you need to add:

   ```
   fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $http_X_User;
   ```

   into nginx/apache configuration.

If you will use same cookie name and secret pair in oauth2 proxy configuration, you will be authenticated to all your systems (Graylog SSO plugin, Icinga2, any your site) with pure SSO experience.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much information is available, you can add a [custom application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps) to Azure AD.

This way only allows the connection to be SAML.